# How can i control size of images using an Array/Bitmapping?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-bitmap

the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vp3Y.png)

I have an an image gallery that swipes left,but now i get the error as shown in the screen shot above.

My solution
This is  linked to the layout with one image view within A Relative Layout:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai559.png)

```
public class SlideImage extends AppCompatActivity{


    ImageView bitmapIV;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.slide_image_layout);


        bitmapIV = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chevrolet_equinox_2001_0);
        Bitmap bitmap =((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        bitmapIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        bitmapIV = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Drawable drawable1 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chevrolet_equinox_2001_1);
        Bitmap bitmap1 =((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        bitmapIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



        bitmapIV = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Drawable drawable2 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chevrolet_equinox_2001_2);
        Bitmap bitmap2 =((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        bitmapIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        bitmapIV = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Drawable drawable3 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chevrolet_equinox_2001_3);
        Bitmap bitmap3 =((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        bitmapIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


        bitmapIV = (ImageView)  findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        Drawable drawable4 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.chevrolet_equinox_2001_4);
        Bitmap bitmap4 =((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        bitmapIV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);




    }
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
09-25 17:30:25.534 2582-2582/com.example.batyaa.firstgearautomotive_2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.batyaa.firstgearautomotive_2, PID: 2582
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 19133580 byte allocation with 8584576 free bytes and 8MB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:1080)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2635)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2540)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:806)
        at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:458)
        at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:463)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:203)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource(AppCompatImageHelper.java:86)
        at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource(AppCompatImageView.java:94)
        at com.example.batyaa.firstgearautomotive_2.cars.chevrolet_equinox_2001.sliderAdapter_ChevroletE.instantiateItem(sliderAdapter_ChevroletE.java:63)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:1010)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1224)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:273)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

ALSO NOTE EVEN WITHOUT MY SOLUTION I GET THE SAME ERROR.

Comment: Please paste the logcat here instead of sending pictures. Also, what is the size of the picture you are trying to use-get? 8 mb? Thanks for following Stack Overflow rules BTW :)

Comment: I'm assuming they are 8MB the log cats also tells me it is 8.

Comment: Use a ViewPager that will not load all bitmaps at once. Second, downsample the imag eby using Bitmap.Config inSample = 4 (or a suitable not so lossly number)

Comment: How do i choose a ViewPager that doesn't load them all at once. What i have is one images when user swipes left the second image appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failed to allocate a ***19133580 byte allocation*** with **8584576** free bytes
>   and **8MB** until OOM

Like i guessed, the `Bitmap` file size you are trying to open-use **is 8MB** which is too much for a file on Android.

Instead, reduce the size of the `Bitmap` by online websites or resize the file and then you'll be good to go.

Comment: So all i have to do is resize it online? then import the images regularly and it will work?

Comment: The point is, if you're trying to show few images like that, as your logcat said, and if they got huge images, so yes. Those images must be resized and reduced by size and then android can handle them.

Comment: But right now the image size fits perfectly for the app. Cant i resize the image in the layout?

Comment: It fits yes. But, Android actually handles that. So, **the actual image size is definitely bigger than what it shows on Android is**. ;)

Comment: Do you have any good online Website that can control its  size and change it to lower than 8mb?

Comment: Use [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+image+reducer&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIR810IR810&oq=online+image+reducer&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i65l2j0.2878j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). Google is our friend :). However, you can easily resize the picture for example, if it is for showing on the app background so, it must be lower than 600 px. Do you get me? I mean, it depends on where you use the picture. But, don't make the size of the pictures bigger than 600-700 px. Then it will automatically reduce the size and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Glad to hear that. Happy to help pal! :)